# is it possible to execute binary file by using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, binaryfiles

I felt this is very strange to me, I am having a sample binary file called **Sum**. This is file type - `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=6cff4e9ea8b26ee16eafa07599eec08ea629ee09, not stripped`

I need to execute this using ruby by passing *two inputs*. I am not aware of this, so is it possible to achieve this using Ruby on Rails. I am really apologise if my explanation is obscure. Thanks in advance.